# iPhone Internet connection problem analysis on phone network

Tags: iphone, internet, cellular-data, network

I have a similar "Internet unreachable" problem with 3 different versions of iOS: 8, 9 & 10.
Unfortunately I can't reproduce it.
The same problem occurs with 2 different mobile phone operators.

Here are the common facts I was able to register on an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.3.1.

1. Mobile phone network is OK:
   [image: no_Internet settings]
2. All other possible Network connecions are off (Bluetooth, Wi-Fi).
3. Any web browser give an error message clearly stating the Internet
   is unreachable:
   [image: Safari_no_Internet][image: Firefox_no_Internet]
4. All other application using the Internet are endlessly looping
   without any clear error message.

It is clear that the iPhone either doesn't have a valid IP address or doesn't have a correct routing information to reach the Internet.

---

In such a case how to diagnose clearly if the problem is a software
failure coming from iOS or a failure coming from the mobile phone network?

Comment: Are you using a Global Proxy (usually setup though Apple Configurator or an MDM) or do you have a VPN?

Comment: Not on this mobile phone network connection at the time of this problem. But I use a VPN at some other times. I will check if the problem might be caused by an abnormal exit from my VPN and add this information to my question.